# Handle item level permission for lists in SharePoint 2013 (OOTB)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, permissions, ootb

Is there anyway to handle item level permission for lists in SharePoint 2013 (OOTB, no code or workflow)?

Is it possible to make a list only allow users to CRUD the items they have created?

Comment: Can you add more details to your question?

Comment: Is it possible to make a list only allow users to CRUD the items they have created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to List Settings -> General Settings -> Advanced Settings. Here you will find out of the box Item-level Permissions for the list.

Comment: Perfect answer.. I have asked another question similar like this. Can you look into this? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136010/set-item-level-permission-for-lists-in-sharepoint-2013